# set javascript array from DataTable in code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Im trying to set an array in `Javascript`, and then give it values from the `DataTable` in the  code behind like that :

```
for (var i = 0; i < '<%=dt_questionVideo.Rows.Count - 1 %>'; i++) {
        videoQarray[i] = '<%=Convert.ToInt32(dt_questionVideo.Rows['+i+'][0]) %>';
    }
```

Im getting an error

> Too many characters in character literal

how can I manuover this one ?

Comment: Maybe
videoQarray[i] = '<%=Convert.ToInt32(dt_questionVideo.Rows[i][0]) %>';

Comment: Perhaps build the entire array serverside instead?

Comment: @JamesKyburz if I try this one, it says that The name 'i' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @geekchic thanks, but I have to make it on client side

Comment: Ok, well I don't think that method will work. I believe the server tags are executed before the javascript. Any particular reason it needs to be client side?

Comment: If your datatable is somehow represented in a grid, you can wrap each of your values in an element such that you could query it via jQuery and construct your array in javascript if the solution I proposed is unacceptable.  That being said, if you're planning on getting the information from a serverside DataTable, I can't imagine why my solution would not work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really do it that way.  If you need a javascript array like that, you're going to have to do something like this in the code behind:

```
        int[] videoQarray = new int[dt_questionVideo.Rows.Count - 1];
        for (var i = 0; i < dt_questionVideo.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
            videoQarray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt_questionVideo.Rows[i][0]);
        }

        string createArrayScript = string.Format("var videoQarray = [{0}];", string.Join(",", videoQarray));

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "registerVideoQArray", createArrayScript, true);
```

Comment: and then I can use the "registerVideoQArray" as my client array ?

Comment: no, 'videoQarray' will be your array.  "registerVideoQArray" is just a unique name provided to the script manager.